# How to show a widget only when user swipes down?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

How can I show a widget in Flutter only when the user swipes down like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1hhc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Use GestureDetector widget in the place where you want the user to swipe. It has alot of options like double tap, long press, vertical and horizontal drags and many more.

`GestureDetector( //onHOrizontalDrag Options );`